# data dictionary package

Tags: r, data-dictionary

Is there a data dictionary package that will work for R.

I have located a data_dict package in the following link for R, however, it will not run on the version of R I am using.
http://optimumsportsperformance.com/blog/creating-a-data-dictionary-function-in-r/

I am looking for a data dictionary package that will make light work of a number of large and complex data tables... I have heard these elusive data dictionary packages exist.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. RStudio is just an IDE, it doesn't impact how R runs. Also, by data dictionary do you mean a summary statistics of the data?

Comment: I hoping to run a script to extract in tabular form the following by way of example;  data field, data type, data range, etc.  I understand that there might be an R package that can achieve this.

Comment: Maybe the skimr package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skimr/vignettes/skimr.html

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look.  However, I was hoping for a dedicated data dictionary package. Will check out the skimr package functionality.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package that might be what you're after. It's on CRAN under datadictionary, but it might be better to use the [dev version](https://github.com/DoctorBJones/datadictionary) on Github because it handles difftimes and dates better.

Comment: Thank you for the dev version link.  I have tested it out on my data and it looks great.  How would I go about adding columns and changing column titles.

Comment: Thanks for checking it out! It only describes your data, so if you want different variables/ variable names you would need to modify the dataset that it is describing.
 
You can add variable labels if you'd like descriptions for your variables. You just pass a named vector to the var_labels argument. There is a bit of an issue with this: sometimes it will accept a selection of variables and sometimes it will only accept a vector of the same length as the df. Not sure why, but I recommend adding a label to all columns atm.